# AS400 - Data downloading to Excel from AS400 table with multiple members

Tags: excel, odbc, ibm-midrange

I recently started a job at a company that still uses AS400 and need some help!

So currently we do not have any BI tool to access system data files directly, so I'm trying to connect AS400 to excel using ODBC and download/display AS400 data directly to excel.

So I accomplished to make the connection and I am able to access schema, table, views from Excel using data connection.  But the problem is that some tables have multiple members in it and the excel's pulling data from what I am guessing as the first member that excel sees when all the important data are in other member files...

Is there anyway I could select specific members and download data of that specific member directly to excel?

I can do this when I use IBM's data transfer program, but I would like to find out if it's possible to do directly with excel..

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 0):

**No.**

Multi-membered files are generally not supported by any SQL tool.

**However**
You can always `CREATE ALIAS myname FOR MYLIB/MYTABLE(MYMBR)`

Then use `myname` to access from Excel.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer!!!  But how do I create ALIAS without using SQL????????  Everything has to be done with Excel or ODBC Driver....

Comment: Normally, you'd use a interactive SQL tool.  STRSQL in green screen or the GUI Run SQL Scripts.  Both those are provided by IBM.  You can also use generic SQL tools such a Toad or SQuirreL.  Within Excel, your only choice would be VBA.

Comment: @Matthew - "Excel or ODBC Driver" is a very different proposition than "directly with Excel"! Your question should be precise about what the requirements are.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I followed the instruction and entered the create alias statement on the RUN SQL SCRIPTS but now I'm getting below error message.


> CREATE ALIAS OPENARUS FOR VINFILES#/ARARL104(M500)

SQL State: 42833
Vendor Code: -5016
Message: [SQL5016] Qualified object name ARARL104 not valid. Cause . . . . . :   One of the following has occurred: -- The syntax used for the qualified object name is not valid for the naming option specified.  With system naming, the qualified form of an object name is schema-name/object-name.

Comment: Appears you have Run SQl Scripts set to SQL naming...either change it to system in the JDBC properties, or use `VINFILES#.ARARL104(M500)`

Comment: @Charles Thank you so much!!!  It worked!!!  Now I can create a datalink between AS400 and Excel and do a direct data download!!!!

Answer (score 0):

**Download a file multiple members to excel**

create a logical file over the physical file with all members.  Download the logical file with excel data connection.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can access the data in multi-member files via FTP. For example /QSYS.LIB/your_library.LIB/your_file.FILE will be considered a directly by FTP. Depending on the data structure you may be able to do it directly from Excel.